# How to specify default value for RequestParam of type Map<String, String>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is there a way to specify a default value for a `RequestParam` of type `Map<String, String>`?

```
public List<Results> getResults(@RequestParam(defaultValue="{sort=date, date.dir=asc}" Map<String, String> searchParams) {

for(String key: searchParams.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(searchParams.get("key")); //Doesn't print anything.
}

}
```

The above doesn't print anything as the `Map` has been initialised, but not populated. Is there a way to specify default values for the `Map` above?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't do a null/empty check on `searchParams` and then populate it with a default map within the method? I'm curious why you'd like to do this within the annotation.

Comment: I thought it would be cleaner with a default value.

Comment: There might be a way to do this in the annotation, but if you do it within the method it'll achieve the same results and unblock you. I'd give this about 5-10m of Googling and then just do it in the method. Clean is a little over rated in my opinion. Putting this in the body will make it clear what you're doing and will be easy to maintain if you want to update in the future. If you want to adjust the default value in the annotation if the future you might need to Google it again to figure out how to make the changes you want (it might be more trouble than it's worth).

Answer (score 0):

Replace Map with your custom class, like MySearchCriteria and provide defaults for the fields